# TypeScript generics: what if Promise reject and resolve types differ?

Tags: typescript, angular-promise, angular-services, typescript2.0, typescript-generics

Simple and common Angular2+ data service that handles errors and uses Promises:

```
// imports skipped

class DataType {}

class Error {
  constructor(error: HttpResponse) {
    this.error = error.json()
  }
}


@Injectable()
export class MyService<DataType> {
  apiUrl = 'my/url';
  constructor(protected http) {}

  get(): Promise<DataType[] | Error> {
    return this.http
    .get(this.apiUrl)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  protected handleError(error: HttpResponse): Promise<Error> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error);
    return Promise.reject(new Error(error));  
  }
}
```

In this class, `get` method returns a Promise, which resolves with `DataType[]` array, and rejects with `Error` type.

Compiling this code, I'm getting this error:

> Type 'Error | DataType[]' is not assignable to type 'DataType'. Type 'Error' is not assignable to type 'DataType'.

I'm using TypeScript version 2.4.2. I'm sure this started happening after TypeScript upgrade, which made types checks more strict.

I want to know how to handle rejection with different type in newest TypeScript. Are there different practices for doing this?

Update: I've found a corresponding bug report, not solved yet https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7588

### **UPDATE**

I've created a repo demonstrating the problem, with two commits. First commit uses `<TypeResolve | TypeReject>` approach, second uses `<TypeResolved>` only. Both commits seem to not compile in real life.

Comment: The generic type constraint for promises only refers to the `resolve` type. The `reject` type is always `any`.

Comment: @NitzanTomer it seems to me you are not right. Typescript expects `reject` type to be the same as `resolve` type

Comment: No, it does not. The reject type is always `any`, regardless of the resolve type. When you say `Promise<string>` then only the resolve type is `string`, the reject type can be anything (`any`)

Comment: You don't want `Promise<DataType[] | Error>` you just want `Promise<DataType[]>`

Comment: @NitzanTomer @Ben I've created a repo where I have put code that does not compile in any way, with ` | Error` or without it. 

https://github.com/easy-one/promise_typescript

Comment: That's way too much code to go through. Please reproduce the problem in playground, that would be the best.

Answer (score 7):

The type parameter for `Promise` is only the type for `.resolve`, not for `.reject`. The type for `.reject` is always `any`, because the type cannot be known at compile time. One of the reasons for this is that `async` functions, which return promises, could potentially reject their promises with any exception.

You should write `Promise<DataType[]>` instead, and check the error type at runtime where you handle errors.

Comment: I may mistake, but Typescript throws an exception in my case. I hope this is a bug they will fix